# What really is abstract data type in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am really tired searching about what is really abstract data type in python?

I found this statement everywhere:

> ADT defined in terms of its data items and associated operations , not
>   its implementation.

So what exactly this statement means , Please explain.

```
  My question is what is abstract data type in python and is it same as abstraction
 in python object oriented ?
```

If you explain with good theory and provide links with good article and blogs that would be helpful for me.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, blog, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Where did you get the phrase "abstract data type" from?  Trouble is, what might be a big deal in languages like C++ is very simple in Python.  All Python is object oriented, your question implies there is a non-oo and an oo Python.  There is only one.

Comment: Data types and object oriented paradigm are completely different things.

Comment: Python-libraries `abc` and `interface` and also abstract classes might be useful here.

Answer (score -2):

An abstract data type in python is one which you would make yourself,

Take for example a `list` and a `hashset`, they both form an abstract data type `dictionary` even though in python it would appear as a build in. Abstraction is the technique in which you can make abstract data types or it can be viewed as a concept rather that a data type.

I'm not sure if I can provide any links, you learn this stuff at university.